# If $X \mapsto X^tG$ is an isomorphism, then $G$ is an invertible matrix. (Bilinear forms)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form, transpose

Let $f : E \times F \to R$ be a bilinear form that is non-singular on the left, where $E, F$ are free $R$-modules of dimension $n$ (both of them).

Then if $X, Y$ are column vectors for general elements $x,y \in E, F$ respectively.  Then the value $f(x,y)$ can be written as:

$$
f(x,y) = X^t G Y
$$

Lang's *Algebra* on page 529 says that $X \mapsto X^t G$ is an isomoprhism (by non-singularity), and that isomorphic here implies that $G$ is invertible.  How do we prove that $G$ is invertible, since things are unfamiliar from the usual way of matrix multiplying, i.e. $a(x) = AX$?

---

$G$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with entries in $R$.

Comment: To be clear, does "nonsingular on the left" means for all $y \in F$ fixed, the function $f(-, y): E \longrightarrow R$ is nonzero?

Comment: Suppose $X$ satisfies $G^tX=0$. If $\phi(X)=X^tG$, then $$\phi(X)=(G^tX)^t=0^t=0$$ Since $\phi$ is an isomorphism we must have $X=0$. This shows the kernal of $G^t$ is the zero vector implying $G^t$ is invertible. Hence so is $G$.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop non-singular on the left means that $\varphi_f : E \to \text{Hom}(F, R)$ is an isomorphism where $\varphi(f)(x) = (y \mapsto f(x, y))$ is just "currying arguments".

Comment: @MatthewPilling I understand all of that!  Except maybe the part that $\ker \phi = 0$ implies invertible.  Is that because of rank-nullity theorem?  I know that it would imply injectivity in general for $R$-module homs.

Comment: We're *given* that $\phi$ is an isomorphism so we already know that $\ker \phi$ is the zero vector. We exploited the fact that $\phi$ is an isomorphism to deduce that $\ker G^t$ is the zero vector. Can you prove that $\ker G^t$ being the zero vector implies that $G^t$ is injective? Once you're able to show that $G^t$ is injective then you have that $G^t$ is invertible.

Comment: @MatthewPilling what theorem is that?

Comment: If $l(X)=G^tX$ is injective then $l$ maps its domain bijectively onto into its image. You're given that $\phi$ is an isomorphism so the image of $l$ must be its entire codomain i.e. $l$ is a bijection too. You can construct the inverse of $G^t$ explicitly by finding $X_i$ so that $G^tX_i=e_i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can revert back to a familiar way of matrix multiplication by exploiting the transpose operator as follows.

Define $\phi:R^{n \times 1} \rightarrow R^{1\times n}$ and $l:R^{n \times 1} \rightarrow R^{n \times 1}$ by $$\phi(X)=X^tG$$ $$l(X)=G^tX$$ Now $\phi(X)^t=l(X)$ for all $X\in R^{n\times 1}$ so $l$ is also an isomorphism. For each $1 \leq i \leq n$ find a unique $X_i\in R^{n\times 1}$ such that $$l(X_i)=G^tX_i=e_i$$ Such an $X_i$ exists by isomorphism. If $M$ is the matrix whose $i^{\text{th}}$ column is $X_i$ then its easy to see that $(G^t)^{-1}=M$ hence $G^t$ is invertible and so is $G$.